# Как посредством метода contains() в Java отличить SA-30 от SA-3 или же SA-1 от SA-1 RC

Tags: java, строки

Имеем строки:

```
1. 17:14:47     352765  SA-30   Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан
2. 20:15:31     352765  SA-3    Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан
3. 16:32:14     352765  SA-1 RC     Запрос 'ErrorLog' успешно обработан
4. 20:15:31     352765  SA-1    Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан
```

Как посредством `if (line.contains("SA-1")) res=line;` выбрать только строку 4 и не выбрать строку 3?

Результат должен быть следующим:

```
res=20:15:31    352765  SA-1    Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан
```

Если для 3 и 4 строки нет решения, то подскажите, как быть с SA-30 от SA-3, то есть, с 1-й и 2-й строками?

Comment: Для строковых переменных такой метод не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто проверяете с пробелами. Т.е чем точнее поиск тем меньше данных. Не мучайте себя. Исключайте не нужные путем добавления данных

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String[] str =
    new String[] {
      "17:14:47 352765 SA-30 Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан",
      "20:15:31 352765 SA-3 Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан",
      "16:32:14 352765 SA-1 RC Запрос 'ErrorLog' успешно обработан",
      "20:15:31 352765 SA-1 Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан"
    };

Stream.of(str).filter(item -> item.contains(" SA-3 ")).forEach(System.out::println);
// 20:15:31 352765 SA-3 Запрос 'Messages' успешно обработан
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать просто идти от большего к меньшему:

```
if(line.contains("SA-30"))
{
 //Найдена 1 строка
} 
else if(line.contains("SA-3"))
{
 //Найдена 2 строка
}
else if(line.contains("SA-1 RC"))
{
 //Найдена 3 строка
}
else if(line.contains("SA-1"))
{
 //Найдена 4 строка
}
```